# Running persistent program in parallel to Java Spring API

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I've just started learning Java Spring, and I'm looking to build an API that serves data scraped from an online marketplace using a python script. The problem is, I'm not entirely sure how to go about connecting the two. As far as I've been able to figure out, the python program should be able continuously run, and write the most recent market data to a database, which Spring can simply pull from. But how would I go about actually getting a python program(or even a normal, separate Java program) to run independently of the main API, while still being able to connect to the database?

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE, and currently have these dependencies:

```
-Spring Boot DevTools
-Spring Web
-H2 Database
-Spring Data JPA
```

Any ideas, or extra resources on the subject would also be very appreciated

Comment: This may be better suited for a tutorial to answer. The question should focus on one specific issue you may have with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why don't you consider write data into *MySQL* in your python script? Then your Spring API can pull from MySQL instead of H2 Database.